# Passing the first letters of a filename to a variable

Tags: bash, mkv

I have video files that have the episode number followed by the episode title,
e.g. 01-pilot.mkv
I just want to use the first two characters to pass on to a variable to pick up a line in a text file, but I'm having difficulty with the syntax.
If I write:
`for mkvfile in *.mkv; do echo "$mkvfile" | cut -c 1-2 ; done`
I get the correct result on the screen:

```
01
02
03
04
```

If I try pass the results on to a variable, I can't because I'm useless at the syntax.
My thought was:
`for mkvfile in *.mkv; do num= $(mkvfile | cut -c 1-2) ; echo "$num" ; done`

I get:

```
mkvfile: command not found

mkvfile: command not found

mkvfile: command not found

mkvfile: command not found

mkvfile: command not found

mkvfile: command not found
```

(I would use "$num" later to pick out the line in the text file later - I just want to see if it works, and it doesn't)
I just can't seem to get when to use quotes, brackets, etc.

Comment: `num= $(echo $mkvfile ...` , `$(...)` returns a result of some command's execution.

Comment: `num=01-pilot.mkv; echo "${numr%-*}"` or `num=01-pilot.mkv; echo "${num:0:2}"` the former is portable syntax and the latter is specific to `bash`. No need to involve `cut` or any external tool from the shell, a [P.E.](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) should suffice.

Comment: In your case `echo "${mkvfile%-*}"` or `echo "${mkvfile:0:2}"` the `$(...)` Command Substitution is also not needed. The error you're having is due to the space in the assignment. There should be no spaces in between the `=` sign.

Comment: (1) Use an array, not just a variable. It makes everything easier. (2) There is no need for `cut` or external processes; Bash can do this: `for mkvfile in *.mkv; do echo "${mkvfile%%-*}"; done` could be the first approximation. And then just store the results into an array for further processing instead of printing them: `for mkvfile in *.mkv; do some_array+=("${mkvfile%%-*}"); done`. If you want to preserve the leading `0`, the array would have to be a string array (`declare -a`), not an integer array (`declare -ai`) — which is no big deal, just good to know.

Comment: Thank you.    This has helped.   Now on to the next part, and a new thread..